# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'users'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to import a table from my "users" app but it keeps failing. Prior to this moment I have imported tables from the app into different files in another app without errors.

Here's the stacktrace when I try to run a script from within the app:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trending_tweets.py", line 9, in <module>
    from users.models import Country
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'users'
```

Here's the `trending_tweets.py` file:

```
import yweather
import tweepy
from decouple import config

# from django.apps import apps

from users.models import Country
# countries = apps.get_model('users', 'Country')


class TrendingTweets:

    """
    Class to generate trending tweets within bloverse
    countries
    """

    def __init__(self):
        """ 

        configuration settings to connect twitter API
        at the point of initialization.

        """
        self.api_key = config('TWITTER_API_KEY')
        self.twitter_secret_key = config('TWITTER_SECRET_KEY')
        self.access_token = config('ACCESS_TOKEN')
        self.access_token_secret = config('ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET')


    def twitter_api(self):
        """

        authentication method to configure twitter settings.

        """
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(self.api_key, self.twitter_secret_key)
        auth.set_access_token(self.access_token, self.access_token_secret)
        api = tweepy.API(auth)

        return api # auth request object


    def generate_woeid(self):
        """
        method to generate WOEID of each country
        on our platform
        """
        client = yweather.Client()

        woeid_box = []

        countries = Country.objects.all()
        for country in countries:
            woeid = client.fetch_woeid(country.name)
            woeid_box.append(woeid)

        return woeid_box



if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = TrendingTweets()
    r = x.generate_woeid()
    print(r)
```

Read about circular imports but still can't find a way to solve this. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my folder structure:

[image: current folder structure]

Also, using:

```
from django.apps import apps
countries = apps.get_model('users', 'Country')
```

returns this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trending_tweets.py", line 11, in <module>
    countries = apps.get_model('users', 'Country')
  File "/home/myPC/Documents/CODE/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 190, in get_model
    self.check_models_ready()
  File "/myPC/myPc/Documents/CODE/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 132, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

My settings.py `INSTALLED_APPS` list:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # local apps
    'users',
    'api',
    'posts',
    'generator',

    # third-party
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_framework_swagger',
    'corsheaders',
]
```

Comment: Hi, tell me your directory architecture.

Comment: can you share your file/directories structure?

Answer (score 2):

Import using `apps` module.

```
from django.apps import apps
mymodel = apps.get_model('users', 'Country')
```

And also make sure you order the apps properly in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`. Loading them in the wrong order can cause modules to *not* be loaded.

You can learn more about that [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/applications/#django.apps.apps.get_model),

Comment: This returns `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.`

Comment: You may not set up your defined model `user`.

[Models | Django documentation | Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#using-models)

Comment: Yes, I did. The `users` app is listed in `installed apps`

Comment: @kinGKong Try reordering the models. Keep your `users` app at the top the `INSTALLED_APPS` list. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I let you try `python manage.py check` on your console. And you see any error.

Comment: @ShinyaOta the local server runs correctly and `check` returns no issue. But after navigating into the `generator` app and running a specific script there, the error pops up.

Comment: @kinGKong Reorder the apps in your `INSTALLED_APPS` properly. That should fix the problem.

Comment: @kinGKong try this

 [Django Activating Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial02/#activating-models)

Comment: @kinGKong OK, I wanna try again.

Can you load `Country` model or any model in Interactive mode?
I wanna simply your problem.

like

```python
from users.models import Country 
```

Comment: Yes, I can load the model in interactive mode